# External Aspnet Web Api Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, ionic2, asp.net-web-api2

I am using https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus for external authentication in a mobile app. In the response from google I get the following:

```
obj.email          // 'email@gmail.com'
obj.userId         // user id
obj.displayName    // 'My Name'
obj.idToken        // idToken that can be exchanged to verify user identity.
obj.serverAuthCode // Auth code that can be exchanged for an access token and refresh token for offline access
```

I am interested in taking this response, and sending it to my .Net Web API to register/login a user.

I was wondering how I should format the http request coming from my client, and what the method in the AccountController.cs would look like to properly handle the request, and pass back a local token to be used throughout the rest of the application.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?